# What does /= mean in C#?

Tags: c#, syntax, operators, division

I am having a tough time googling `/=`... can anyone tell me what this code does?

```
number = digits[n % digits.Length] + number;
n /= digits.Length;
```

My intent is to determine what the remainder of this operation is... so I know when to stop or keep going.

Comment: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Sharp_Programming/Operators#Short-hand_Assignment

Comment: Thanks for all the help.  I can accept an answer in 11 minutes..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the division assignment operator operator meaning `n = n/digits.Length`

See [MSDN: /= Operator (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d31sybc9.aspx) for details.

Answer (score 4):

Just to add to what has already been posted in various answers, a compound assignment operator `$=` (replace `$` with a binary operator) is *similar* to an assignment with the binary operator used in the right-hand side. The difference is that the left-hand side is evaluated only once. So:

```
x $= y
```

`x` is evaluated only once.

```
x = x $ y
```

`x` is evaluated twice.

Unlikely to make a difference in practice.

Comment: If you say: `DoHeavyWorkCauseSideEffectsAndReturnObject().MyIntProperty /= 100;`, then it might make a difference compared to `DoHeavyWorkCauseSideEffectsAndReturnObject().MyIntProperty = DoHeavyWorkCauseSideEffectsAndReturnObject().MyIntProperty / 100;`. But most of the time you split it into two statements, and so you're right, there's no practical difference.

Answer (score 1):

`x /= y` means `set x equal to (in this case the integral part of) 'x divided by y'`.  `/` is the division operator.

Answer (score 0):

Same as

```
n += 4; // adds 4
n *= 4; // 4 times
```

just division.

Answer (score 0):

Per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d31sybc9.aspx), these two are equivalent:

```
 n /= digits.Length;
```

and

```
 n = n/digits.Length;
```

Similar to the more commonly seen:

```
n+=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

`/=` is a division operator.

```
x /= y ;
```

is the same thing as saying:

```
x = x / y ;
```